# Iterating over controllers in solution

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to get a list of all public methods that return an ActionResult from any controller in my solution using reflection but I am experiencing some strange behavior.

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MyDLL.MvcApplication));

var controllerActionList = asm.GetTypes().ToList();
```

If I run the above code I get a list of all my types including all my models and controllers etc. just like I would expect. However, if I modify it and run the below code my results list comes back empty. Any idea what's going on here? I would think this should filter the types down so I get a list of all the controllers right?

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MyDLL.MvcApplication));

var controllerActionList = asm.GetTypes()
    .Where(type => typeof(Controller).IsAssignableFrom(type)).ToList();
```

Comment: Your code really should work.  Instead of typeof(Controller), can you try typeof(System.Web.Mvc.Controller)?  Then, any subclasses of System.Web.Mvc.Controller really should be reported.

Comment: Ya I already tried that and it didn't work but I got it working in a weird way. I think the .net version this project is using isn't exactly the same as the one the target dll is using and it's causing the type comparison to always fail. Check my answer below for how I got it doing what I want. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by using the code below. I think the direct type comparison is failing for me because I believe I have two different .net versions between these 2 projects.

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(SCCView.MvcApplication));

var controllerActionList = asm.GetTypes()
    .Where(type => type.BaseType.Name == "Controller")
    .SelectMany(type => type.GetMethods())
    .Where(
        m => m.IsPublic && m.ReturnType.Name == "ActionResult")
    .Select(x => new {Controller = x.DeclaringType.Name, Action = x.Name})
    .OrderBy(x => x.Controller).ThenBy(x => x.Action).ToList();
```

The above will give you a paired list of every public method in a controller that returns an ActionResult